# How do I add a custom Folder Type to use as a template in Windows Vista (or Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I'm looking for a way to add a custom setting to the list of folder types in Vista (or Windows 7) so that I can use it as a template for other folders.

The template I'd like to add would be identical to All Items, except also have the Date Taken column displayed. How do I add to this list (see image below)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was really curious about this question as well so I tried to look everywhere I could. The farthest I got was [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762581(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN.

It looks like these data you're looking for are stored in the registry key here:  `hkey_local_machine/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/explorer/FolderTypes`

Unfortunately I'm no registry expert so I only went so far as to search out the key and investigate. However, the FOLDERTYPEID constants specified by Microsoft do not appear to be in there. Sorry that's not a complete answer but I searched everywhere and all I could find was more questions on the same topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to add a new template, but it is possible to achieve a similar effect by first assigning a folder to a particular template, then altering the specifics within the registry.

You need to identify the particular folder after changing it to one of the existing  templates within the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags\[Whatever]\Shell\
```

where `[Whatever]` will be any number

There is a `REG_SZ` string Value named `FolderType` for the TEMPLATE type to use:
i.e. "MyMusic" for Music, "MyPictures" for images, "Documents" for 'Documents of any type'
The text for these is located within the "%WINDIR%/shell.inf" file

The "Vid" `REG_SZ String Value` contains the Class ID for the "watermark" image. At this time, I cannot comment on what filetypes are valid, but bmp, gif, png or jpg should all be attempted.

Answer (score 0):

As one cannot find the names of the standard folder types in the registry, I believe that unfortunately they are built-into the Windows software.

As a proof I found, for example, "Pictures and Videos" as a unicode string inside shell32.dll. Moreover, it was found among other non-related strings. So it doesn't seem that there was any attempt to package together all the folder types, meaning that they were added one-by-one as new types were invented by the UI designers of Microsoft.

I am afraid that this makes your request impossible.
In any case, I don't believe you would want to hack shell32.dll.